# Question on the "Tutorial implementation of dependently typed lambda calculus"

Tags: logic, type-theory

I have a slight technical struggle with [this](https://www.andres-loeh.de/LambdaPi/LambdaPi.pdf) marvelous tutorial. On page 5 the tutorial talks about typing rules for Simply Typed Lambdas and presents following judgement as derivable via rules on figure 3.

I was unable to prove neither `id` nor `const` by the same reason. Take for instance the `id` example.

- Say I am looking on type checking rule `CHK`. It says that in order to `check types` I should first perform inference and then compare result with what I expect.
- To do the inference on application, I have to use the `APP` rule that immediately forces me to infer the type of the left hand side of the application, namely `(id :: α -> α)`
- To do that I am using the `ANN` rule that forces me to check that `α -> α` is a type (and I can prove it no problem). Then I got this naked `id` symbol and have to prove it's type to be `α -> α`.
- Finally, here is a problem. In order to do that I will have to use `var` rule, which requires the type of `id` to be set in the context Gamma explicitly, but it is not done, therefore the proof is falling apart.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$\mathsf{id}$ and $\mathsf{const}$ are not variables of the calculus, but syntactic sugar for $\lambda x \rightarrow x$ and $\lambda x \rightarrow \lambda y \rightarrow x$ respectively. This is stated at the end of §2.2 and subtly conveyed by the use of a sans-serif font rather than italics (this is a typographic convention of this particular document, not a common convention).

So for example the type judgement
$$
\alpha :: \ast, y :: \alpha \vdash (\mathsf{id} :: \alpha \rightarrow \alpha) \: y :: \rightarrow \alpha
$$
is also the type judgement
$$
\alpha :: \ast, y :: \alpha \vdash (\lambda x \rightarrow x :: \alpha \rightarrow \alpha) \: y :: \rightarrow \alpha
.
$$
It's a different notation for the same mathematical object.

Comment: One of the authors of the paper/tutorial here. I can confirm that this is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

As an example, here is the full derivation for the type judgement
$$\alpha::\ast,y::\alpha \vdash (\lambda x \rightarrow x :: \alpha \rightarrow \alpha) \: y :: \alpha$$
where $\enspace \Gamma = \alpha::\ast,y::\alpha \enspace$ and $\enspace \Gamma' = \Gamma,x::\alpha \enspace$:

$$
{ \dfrac
  { \dfrac
    { \Gamma \vdash \alpha \rightarrow \alpha :: \ast
      \qquad
      \dfrac
        { \dfrac
          { \dfrac
            { \Gamma'(x)=\alpha }
            { \Gamma,x :: \alpha \vdash x ::_\uparrow \alpha } { \tiny VAR }
          }
          { \Gamma,x :: \alpha \vdash x ::_\downarrow \alpha } { \tiny CHK }
        }
        { \Gamma \vdash \lambda x \rightarrow x ::_\downarrow \alpha \rightarrow \alpha } { \tiny LAM }
    }
    { \Gamma \vdash (\lambda x \rightarrow x :: \alpha \rightarrow \alpha) ::_\uparrow \alpha \rightarrow \alpha } { \tiny ANN }
    \qquad
    \dfrac
      { \dfrac
        { \Gamma(y) = \alpha }
        { \Gamma \vdash y ::_\uparrow \alpha } { \tiny VAR }
      }
      { \Gamma \vdash y ::_\downarrow \alpha } { \tiny CHK }
  }
  { \dfrac
    { \Gamma \vdash (\lambda x \rightarrow x :: \alpha \rightarrow \alpha)\ y ::_\uparrow \alpha }
    { \Gamma \vdash (\lambda x \rightarrow x :: \alpha \rightarrow \alpha)\ y ::_\downarrow \alpha } { \tiny CHK }
  } { \tiny APP }
}
$$